# eye tracking and bigvideo.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opencv

I'm working a page that tracks the users eyes and feeds them out to two windows either side of a series of videos. the eye tracking works, sort of in this page. http://harrysanderson.webs.com/neweyestest.html

and the fullscreen video works in this page, although there seem to be some issues with playback freezing up towards the end of the video. (same as others but fullscreendothtml)

however, when i try to combine the two codes it stops the tracking from functioning and all i get is a close up from the webcam feed. Would anyone be able to tell me why this is happening? I'm v. new to js so any help much appreciated.

here is the page as it is at the moment: http://harrysanderson.webs.com/combine1.html

i've been using the js-objectdetect library and bigvideo.js for the background video.